# Configure report generation HTML template in Maven Surefire Java for JUnit

Tags: junit4, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am working on Selenium automation using Java. I am using Maven automation and maven surefire dependency to generate HTML reports of JUnit tests. Default format looks great. But I want to configure HTML format and want Surefire to render my custom HTML format. I tried some options along with "mvn surefire-report:report-only" but those are not working.

mvn execution commands I am using are as follows:

- mvn test
- mvn surefire-report:report-only
- mvn site
  -DgenerateReports=false

Can you please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Run `surefire-report:report` maven goal on your project. This will generate an HTML file under `{project_location}/target/site/surefire-report.html`.

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

See https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html for more details.